# Freezing a Peanut Butter Chip Pound Cake

Tags: freezing

I need to make several pound cakes for Thanksgiving. I make a variety but the are mostly pound cakes. They will be made with fresh eggs. Is it OK to freeze these cakes and how does it affect the taste? How long in advance can I make and freeze?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Your pound cakes will be just as tasty and fresh tasting as if they were baked the same day. Even cake mix variety can be handled the same way and it is absolutely the way to store butter based breads.

I learned the proper storage of cakes from Rose Levy Beranbaum and her Cake Bible. This is not an ad for the book but a suggestion you will not regret if you are are a baker.

If you like, use a little simple syrup and brush over cakes...

You need to allow the cake to come to room temperature. Then, if baked in a bundt pan, put plastic wrap in the center hole. This is to emiminate as much air as possible. Wrap cake in a layer of heavy duty aluminum foil by folding lengthwise, then folding the ends up tightly. Repeat the process in the opposite direction.

The cakes can be stored and frozen for a month or longer. When thawing, bring to room temperature for maximum flavor. I've done wedding cakes this way.